# How to select a specific row from count table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by, having-clause

Is that possible to select a specific row from a group count?

This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    khashrm a
INNER JOIN price_name b WHERE
    (a.type3 = b.name)
GROUP BY
    a.type3
ORDER BY
    `COUNT(*)`
DESC
```

and the result will be :

```
+---------+
| COUNT() |
+---------+
| 1       |
+---------+
| 5       |
+---------+
| 10      |
+---------+
```

I want to select only that row which held 10, BTW this row is changeable, it’s not fixed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the row whose count is `10`, use `having`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM khashrm a
INNER JOIN price_name b ON a.type3 = b.name
GROUP BY a.type3
HAVING COUNT(*) = 10
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you want the third row in the resultset, then that's `limit` and `offset`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM khashrm a
INNER JOIN price_name b ON a.type3 = b.name
GROUP BY a.type3
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

Notes:

- use standard joins; the join condition goes to the `on` clause rather than to the `where` clause
- no need for parentheses around the join condition

Comment: Thank you so much, but this value is changeable. So row 3, it may will be increased anytime.

Comment: @HatemAlshehri: so what you want is the third row, regardless of its value? See my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping. It’s work fine now.